# Runtime bounds on algorithms of NP complete problems assuming P≠NP

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, p-vs-np

Assume $P\neq NP$.

What can we say about the runtime bounds of all NP-complete problems?

i.e. what are the tightest functions $L,U:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ for which we can guarantee that an optimal algorithm for **any** NP-complete problem runs in time of at least $\omega(L(n))$ and at most $o(U(n))$ on a input of length $n$?

Obviously, $\forall c:L(n)=\Omega(n^c)$.
Also, $U(n) = O(2^{n^{\omega(1)}})$.

### Without assuming $QP\neq NP$, $ETH$, or any other assumption which is not implied by $P\neq NP$, can we give any better bounds on $L,U$?

**EDIT:**

Note that at least one of $L,U$ has to be far from the bounds I gave here, since being NPC problems, these problems has poly time reduction between each other, meaning that if some NPC problem has an optimal algorithm of time $f(n)$, then all problems has an algorithm (optimal or not) of runtime $O(f(n^{O(1)}))$.

Comment: if P$\neq$NP we can say that the runtime bounds are larger than any polynomial.... afaik no, better bounds are not known.... a lot of notation doesnt chg that... there do exist superpolynomial-but-subexponential functions eg $2^{\log n}$

Comment: First, $2^{\log n}$ is just linear, so I guess you mean $2^{polylog(n)}$ which is known as the class $QP$.

I fully realize that $P\neq NP$ doesn't mean any NP-complete function will run at exponential time, but that is not what I'm asking.

For example, assuming $P\neq NP$, is it possible that a NPC problem can be solved in $2^{log(n)\cdot log^*(n)}$, where $log^*(n)$ is the inverse Ackermann function?

The notations are merely a tool used for expressing my question formally..

Comment: thx for the correction. very little is known in this area afaik. try this question [NTime(n^k) =? DTime(n^k)](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/ntimenk-dtimenk) tcs.se

Comment: @RB While it is true that in each "possible world" there are lower and upper bounds which are roughly within a polynomial of each other, it is not clear what *a priori* bounds are possible.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of the question is that is asks about the possibilities in *relativized worlds*. Suppose that in some relativized world, $P \neq NP$. Can we deduce anything non-trivial about the time complexity of NP-complete problems? The [Baker–Gill–Solovay argument](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs468/BGS.pdf) shows that we can "force" some NP problem to require exponential time, so the upper bound given in the question is essentially optimal.

Regarding the lower bound, we sketch below a proof that relative to some oracle, $NP = \mathrm{TIME}(2^{O(\log^2 n)})$. Assuming that the sketched proof is correct, we can also apply it to functions smaller than $2^{O(\log^2 n)}$, and this shows that the lower bound given in the question is also essentially tight.

**Proof sketch.** We construct two oracles $O_1,O_2$: the first behaves like a $\mathrm{TIME}(2^{O(\log^2 n)})$-complete problem, and the second implements the Baker–Gill–Solovay diagonalization. It is straightforward to pack both oracles into a single oracle.

The oracle $O_1$ consists of all pairs $\langle M, x \rangle$ such that $M$ is an oracle Turing machine that accepts $x$ in running time $2^{2^{\sqrt{\log |x|}}}$ when given access to the oracles $O_1,O_2$ restricted to inputs of length at most $2^{\sqrt{\log |x|}}$. (This is not a circular definition.)

The oracle $O_2$ is defined in the same way that the oracle is defined in Baker–Gill–Solovay: for each clocked oracle Turing machine $M$ running in time $T = 2^{o(\log^2 n)}$, we find some input length $n$ which is "untouched", run $M$ on $1^n$ for $T$ steps, and for each query to $O_2$ of size $n$, we mark that this input is not in $O_2$ (for other queries we also mark that the input is not there, unless we had already decided that it is in $O_2$). Queries to $O_1$ are handled similarly (as implicit queries to $O_1,O_2$ of smaller size, handled recursively); notice that such queries never mention strings of length $n$ in $O_2$, since $2^{\sqrt{\log T}} < n$. If the machine accepts, we mark all other strings of length $n$ in $O_2$ as missing, otherwise we pick some string of length $n$ and put it in $O_2$.

The class $P^{O_1,O_2}$ consists of all programs running in time $2^{2^{O(\sqrt{\log n})}}$, making queries to $O_1,O_2$ of size $2^{O(\sqrt{\log n})}$. The class $NP^{O_1,O_2}$ is of the form $x \mapsto \exists |y|<n^C \varphi(x,y)$, where $\varphi \in P^{O_1,O_2}$, and so it is contained in the class of all programs running in time $2^{n^C}$ and making oracle queries of size
$2^{O(\sqrt{\log n})}$. The latter is contained in $\mathrm{TIME}(2^{\log^2 n^C})^{O_1,O_2}$, since we can use $O_1$ to decide it. This shows that $NP^{O_1,O_2} \subseteq \mathrm{TIME}(2^{O(\log^2 n)})^{O_1,O_2}$.

For the other direction, let $L$ be the language which consists of $1^n$ for each $n$ such that $O_2$ contains some string of length $n$. By construction of $O_2$, $L \notin \mathrm{TIME}(2^{o(\log^2 n)})^{O_1,O_2}$, while clearly $L \in NP^{O_1,O_2}$. This shows that $NP^{O_1,O_2} = \mathrm{TIME}(2^{O(\log^2 n)})^{O_1,O_2}$.

Comment: I have to admint I didn't fully understand your answer, but if, as you mentioned, some NP-complete problem $\Pi$ is only solvable in $\Omega(2^{n^c})$, then all other NPC problems are also only solvable in $\Omega(2^{n^{\Omega(1)}})$, as there's a poly time reduction to them from $\Pi$, which means that otherwise you'd have a better algorithm for $\Pi$.

This implies for example $QP\neq NP$ and $ETH$ doesn't it?
What am I missing?

Comment: Well, it doesn't imply $ETH$, but it does look it may imply $QP\neq NP$.

Comment: You're not missing anything. There is a relativized world in which ETH is true. There is another relativized world where P=NP, and so in particular ETH is false.

Comment: But not in all reletivized worlds in which $P\neq NP$,  $QP\neq NP$ is true as well, right?
There is a chance that $P\subsetneq QP = NP$.
From what I understood from your answer, if $P\neq NP$ there exist a NPC problem whose lower bound is exponential, and I'm wondering why it's true.

Comment: In my answer I (purportedly) give a relativized world in which $NP = \mathrm{TIME}(n^{O(\log n)})$. Another relativized world has $NP = \mathrm{TIME}(2^{n^{O(1)}})$. In yet other relativized worlds, $P=NP$. Regarding $QP$, I don't claim anything about it.